# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

Why the program says

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HamburgerciOrnegi.exe but was not handled in user code

[image: I looked System.NullReferenceException entry and i can't find my answer. If you could help me , i'll be very thankful to you.]

Comment: Probably due to missing try-catch block, use try-catch block to catch it, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: No instance is created for `ManuItem` class, so without instance you can not access class property `Name`.

Comment: You have not created an instance of the `MenuItem` class therefore the variable is `null`. Try `MenuItem = new MenuItem();` before accessing it's properties.

Comment: **I am trying it but it's not working. I think i'm doing it wrong but i don't know how should i write correct.**

Comment: Oh okay i find how to use it. Thank you :)